# Find the total number of factors (excluding $1$) of $2160$.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the total number of factors (excluding $1$) of $2160$.

According to me it's just asking about total number of factors that is  $4+3+1=8$ ($2^4 \cdot 3^3  \cdot 5^1$).  I don't see any statement asking about number of ways of selecting its factors.

But solution of this question is given by taking number of ways of selecting some or all out of four $2$s,three $3$s and one $5$. Number of such ways is $(4+1)(3+1)(1+1)-1=39$.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: The number of such ways is $5\cdot4\cdot2=40$.

Comment: @Bernard No sir it's answer is 39 only.

Comment: I'm sorry, but perform the multiplication. You've forgotten something on writing your argument.

Comment: @Bernard Oops!!! got it

Comment: Please typeset mathematical expressions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$12=2^2\cdot3$$

The possible factors are

$$1,2,4,3,6,12$$ 
respectively $$2^0\cdot3^0,2^1\cdot3^0,2^2\cdot3^0,\\2^0\cdot3^1,2^1\cdot3^1,2^2\cdot3^1.$$

As you see, every prime factor is taken will all multiplicities, and all combinations ($(2+1)(1+1)$ of them) are possible.

Answer (score 2):

Let's not work with such a big number, let's work with $6 = 2^1 \times 3^1$.

By your argument, you are claiming that there are only $1+1=2$ factors.  Perhaps you are just counting $2$ and $3$ and not counting that it is possible to select $6$ as a potential factor.

It seems that you are computing factors of the form of $p^r$ where $r \ge 1$ where $p$ is a prime which is not what the question is asking for.

In general if the prime factorization is $\prod_{i=1}^n p_i ^{m_i}$, then the number of factor is $\prod_{i=1}^n (m_i+1)$ . If you are not counting $1$ as a factor, then we subtract by $1$. The rationale of the formula is for each prime, we can consider how many of copies of a particular prime should be chosen and it is possible that we choose none.

Comment: sir, I don't see statement asking about number of ways.But in solution they are taking number of ways.Please explain this.

Comment: we are counting number of ways to construct a factor. of which, we are just counting number of factors.

Comment: I got it sir.But  sir I still think that this question is not well illustrated .Do you agree or I am just stupid

Comment: you are just not familiar with a particular concept yet, that has nothing to do with intelligence. It takes time and practices to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the prime factors into three groups:
$$2^\color{red}4=1\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2; \ \ \ \ 3^\color{green}3=1\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3; \ \ \ 5^\color{blue}1=1\cdot 5.$$
To form a factor you choose a number from each group. Here are the possible numbers in the groups:
$$\{1,2,2^2,2^3,2^4\}; \ \ \{1,3,3^2,3^3\}; \ \ \{1,5\}.$$
Note that choosing $1$ basically means you do not choose the prime number (in this case $2,3,5$).

So by [the product rule in combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and [the fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic):
$$\begin{align}{5\choose 1}\cdot {4\choose 1}\cdot {2\choose 1}&=5\cdot 4\cdot 2=40 \ \ \text{OR}\\
{\color{red}4+1\choose 1}\cdot {\color{green}3+1\choose 1}\cdot {\color{blue}1+1\choose 1}&=5\cdot 4\cdot 2=40.\end{align}$$